# Clarification of the proof of the euclidean division algorithm for polynomials over a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

[image]

In studying this particular proof, I am confused by the very last line of the proof.

It seems to me that if $h = q_1g + r$ then

$f(x) = q_1g + r + \frac {a_n}{b_m}x^{n-m}g(x)$ so that $q$ should be equal to 
$q_1 +  \frac {a_n}{b_m}x^{n-m}$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  Presumably the equation in the text is supposed to say $$q(x)=(a_n/b_m)x^{n-m}+q_1(x)$$ and the plus sign was just omitted by accident.

Comment: One small mistake can ruin a person's evening.